# Changing the Recipient Type in email

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I m doing and email, using visualforce and i would like to ask you if its possible that the Recipient Type is a field from the masterapplication and not the standard "user, contact, lead", because my user will fill up a field in the master application, where he writes is on email adress , and after i want to send email to tthis email adress in the masterapplication, but is not a user, contact or lead.

Thank u!

Comment: You can create an email field and map this field and mail to external Email Ids that are not the standard "user, contact, lead".

Comment: I already create the email, an set as external ID but doesn appear in the recipent type, only the user, lead....

Comment: can you provide screen shot so we better understand

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/visk5rea7/Capturar.png   I woul like to have in the recipient type a custom field(email) , because like a told you, i want to send email to the email adress that the user fill in the email field

Comment: @MohithKumar ddd